# mongoose find object into array of object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new in mongoose and I'm trying to find user by code [`user.test.test1.code`] , any idea ?

Model :

```
const userSechema = new mongoose.Schema({     
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
     test: [{}],
 })
```

Data :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "600020ab34742c2d34ae45e5"
     },
    "test": [{
       "test1": {
            "code": 11111
        },
       "test2": {
          "code": 22222
        }
      }]
   "name": "daniel"
}
```

query :

```
let regex = new RegExp(req.query.searchUserKey, 'i')
const users = await User.find({ $or: [{'name': regex },{'test.test1': { code : regex} }]})
```

-- Solution --

Thanks you guys, both answers is work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is as simple as do `"test.test1.code": 418816` into find query like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "test.test1.code": 418816
})
```

This query will give you all documents where exists `test.test1.code` with value `418816`.

Note that this query return the whole document, not only the sub-document into the array. But I'm assuming by your post that a `user` is the document where exists the field `name`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mlnlsM8iGsa)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$elemMatch`, check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html)

```
const users = await User.find(
   { test: { $elemMatch: { "test1.code": 418816 } } }
)
```